# select a date lesser than a particular date

Tags: mysql, date

I have stored the dates as string in my database.I know it is not good,but project already has been half developed before i take over and where dates were stored as string,so i was continuing the same way.

Now i want to select dates from table where date is greater than a specific date.

I tried the following query

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 dates 
where
 STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y-%m-%d') > "2014-01-01"
```

but it is not returning only greater values.
Please help me to solve problem.

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d74c3/9)**

Comment: sorry dude,plz check updated demo

Comment: Why are the dates strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dates are not in YYYY-MM-DD format.  Use the right format!

```
SELECT *
FROM dates 
where STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m-%d-%Y') > date('2014-01-01')
```

If you are going to store dates as strings, then the best way is in the ISO format of YYYY-MM-DD.

You should read the documentation on `str_to_date()` ([here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)).

Comment: Thanks man,i thought we want to give the desired format in STR_TO_DATE() function.And thanks for your advice.I will try to implement it in future

Comment: Doesn't `STR_TO_DATE` make a date? so the format is not relevant?

Comment: @Ben . . . Dates can be stored in many different formats in a string -- such as '2014-01-15' or '15-01-2014' or '01Jan2014' or '1/15/14'.  The format is needed to tell the function how to do the conversion.  For this particular question, the dates could actually be Jan 5th and 6th or May 1st and Jun 1st -- depending on the format.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Linoff In Oracle a date is a date regards the presentation to the user using a format. In MySQL it should be the same. Does it make any sense to store a date as date and always to specify a format for comparison?

Comment: @Ben . . . The problem here is that the OP is *not* storing the date as a date, but rather as a string.  The problem is converting that string to a date correctly.

Comment: "Oracle uses its own internal format to store dates. Date data is stored in fixed-length fields of seven bytes each, corresponding to century, year, month, day, hour, minute, and second."
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i1847

Answer (score 0):

What type has the `date`? I'd prefer a `'` instead of `"` for strings in SQL. Let's assume that date is a `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` field (depending on which database you are using):

```
SELECT *
  FROM dates 
 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y-%m-%d') > STR_TO_DATE('2014-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

If `date` is a real `DATE`

```
SELECT *
  FROM dates 
 WHERE trim(date) > STR_TO_DATE('2014-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Or you just convert it into a number format `date_format(date,'%Y%m%d') > 20140101`

Answer (score 0):

Convert everything to date and it should be fine. Now you are comparing date and string.

Comment: converting everything to date is really huge process,as i need to change all old codes according to that